# Routes Redirecting to the login page Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using [Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) for the authentication of my Laravel application. I don't know why but I can't access to my public routes as a guest.

This route is working for guests:

```
Route::get('/course-calendar', function () {
    $events = \App\Models\Event::all();

    return view('public.calendar.index' , compact('events'));
});
```

But when I use a route like this:

```
Route::resource('courses' , 'CourseController');
```

redirects me to the login page. These two routes are at the top of the `route.php`

Here is my controller:

```
 <?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Event; //models are at App\Models

class CourseController extends Controller
{

    //Show lists of the events in the calendar
    public function dekha()
    {
        $events = Event::all();

        return view('public.calendar.index' , compact('events'));
    }

    //show single page
    public function show($id)
    {
        $event = Event::find($id);

        if (is_null($event))
        {
            return Redirect::route('courses');
        }      

        return View::make('public.events.single', compact('event'));
    }

}
```

It seems to be weird . Can you please point out what I am missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing a silly mistake in my `Controller.php` .

I had this:

```
  public function __construct(){

    $this->middleware('auth');

}
```

I had to remove the code block from `controller.php`